# Add property to QML object after QQmlComponent::beginCreate()

Tags: qt, qml

I am looking for a way to add properties in the scope of a certain objects in a QML object tree.

file.qml:

```
import QtQml 2.0

QtObject {
    property var test1: QtObject {
        objectName: "child1"
        property string color: environment.color
    }

    property var test2: QtObject {
        objectName: "child2"
        property string color: environment.color
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtQml>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine,QUrl::fromLocalFile("file.qml"));
    QObject* object = component.beginCreate(engine.rootContext());
    QObject* child1 = object->findChild<QObject*>("child1", Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);
    QObject* child2 = object->findChild<QObject*>("child2", Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);

    QQmlPropertyMap env1;
    QQmlPropertyMap env2;
    env1["color"] = "green";
    env2["color"] = "blue";

    // Now I want to make object1 available for child1
    // and object2 available for child2.
    // But I can't do this:
    //    qmlContext(test1)->setContextProperty("environment", env1);
    //    qmlContext(test2)->setContextProperty("environment", env2);

    component.completeCreate();

    if (!component.errors().isEmpty()) {
        qDebug() << component.errorString();
    }

    Q_ASSERT(child1->property("color") == QString("green"));
    Q_ASSERT(child2->property("color") == QString("blue"));

    qDebug() << "It works";
}
```

I admit that the example above looks a bit odd. It's a simplified variant of the [example I posted in the Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/94150/how-to-add-a-property-to-a-qml-object-after-creation-but-before-binding-evaluation).

Comment: what is `foo`??

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Done.

Comment: the binding can only be given between QObjects since the signals notify the changes, QVariantMap is not a QObject so it will not notify anything.

Comment: Bindings are not evaluated yet, so QVariantMap is totally fine here. But I will use QQmlPropertyMap to make it more clear.

Comment: Are the children of specific types? Why don't you add a property to them prior to creation and set this later? What do you want to use this new property for?

Comment: This code example illustrates only the technical aspect of the problem. The background is explained in the linked Qt forum post.

Comment: The questions (2nd) arose exactly from you linked post. If you analyze and modify the objects, why don't you add a property on the QML-side that you then set from C++? And if the Objects you try to modify are of a specific type, you might try to use extension objects (you would need to import them though).

Comment: I see your point and I think that would work. Thank you for the suggestion. But in my DSL I don't want users to explicitly declare a property for each dependency they define. I want it to happen implicitly, just as in [Qbs](https://doc.qt.io/qbs/) with [module dependencies](https://doc.qt.io/qbs/language-introduction.html#modules).